# `dlopen`ing a DSO from inside that same DSO

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, elf, dlopen

I have a DSO (`mylibrary.so.0` library) with a `func1` function marked as `extern "C"` and which I'm sure it's exported since

```
nm -D mylibrary.so.0 | grep func1
000000000009f9bb T func1 <- symbol is visible and exported
```

This DSO is being loaded in a chain of dependencies I have no control over, e.g.

`executable1 -dlopen-> 3rdpartydispatcher.so -dlopen-> my_library.so.0`

Now, my library has a method which gets called (I can see it's getting called by stepping into it via gdb) and receives a C string with the function name it should call, e.g.

```
void call_function_from_name(const char *function_name) {

    void *mylibrary_so_0 = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW); // (*)
    void *func1 = dlsym(mylibrary_so_0, function_name);
    if (!func1) {
        log_error(dlerror());
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is: even if `call_function_from_name` is being called with argument `func1`, i.e. a perfectly valid and exported symbol, `dlsym` is failing and the error is `executable1 has no func1 symbol`.

I come from a Windows environment and I assumed that `dlopen(NULL, ..)` returns me a handle on the main executable **but** that any subsequent `dlopen`'d library from that executable gets also mapped in its virtual address space and therefore I can use that handle to search for the symbols those libraries exported.

Is my assumption incorrect? If it is, how can I refer to `func1` from within a same-dso function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> `void *mylibrary_so_0 = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW); // (*)`
> ```

For some reason you believe that this should `dlopen` `my_library.so.0`, but it *doesn't* -- it opens the main executable.

The error message clearly tells you that: `executable1 has no func1`.

A possible fix is use `dlopen("my_library.so.0", RTLD_NOW)`, but a much better fix it to provide a *static* map of functions you want to be able to call this way, and use *that*:

```
struct mapping { const char *f_name; void (*f_ptr)(); } = {
  { "func1", &func1 },
  { "func2", &func2 },
  { NULL, NULL },
};
```

Now just search your `mapping`, and call the target function; no `dlsym` required.

Answer (score 0):

Your library was probably loaded with `RTLD_LOCAL` which explicitly doesn't put it in global symbol space. It could call `dlopen` on itself with `RTLD_GLOBAL` to "fix" this if needed, or if you know the needed symbol is in your lib, it could just get a new `RTLD_LOCAL` handle to itself and call `dlsym` on that rather than the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks but how to get a handle to itself? `dlopen(NULL, ..)` called from the library loaded from another library, just gets a handle to the main executable, not the library loaded by another library

Comment: @Dean: It should know its name, so something like `dlopen("myself.so", RTLD_NOW|RTLD_LOCAL)`.